# How to add scrollbar to dropdown menus where menu items are automatically added from datatatables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I need help with adding a scrollbar for dropdown items. The dropdown values are automatcially derived from the table. Here is how it looks like -

I have 3 dropdown lits (dropdown 1, dropdown2 and dropdown 3). Each list has about 30 values. I would like to add a scrollbar maybe after 8 items. How can I do this? Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    searching: true
  });

  buildSelect(table);
  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });


});

function buildSelect(table) {
  var counter = 0;
  table.columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
    var column = table.column(this, {
      search: 'applied'
    });
    counter++;
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo($('#dropdown' + counter).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
      select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
    });

    // The rebuild will clear the exisiting select, so it needs to be repopulated
    var currSearch = column.search();
    if (currSearch) {
      // ** MY CHANGE **
      // Use RegEx to find the selected value from the unique values of the column.
      // This will use the Regular Expression returned from column.search to find the first matching item in column.data().unique
      select.val(column.data().unique().toArray().find((e) => e.match(new RegExp(currSearch))));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox">
<p>Name: <span id="dropdown1">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Postion: <span id="dropdown2">
  </span>
</p>

<p>Office: <span id="dropdown3">
</span>
</p>
  <button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>ID.AI</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett -2</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton.1 -2</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          
            
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
max-height:100px;
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: Please see my code. I am not sure where do I define max-height and overflow?

Comment: on the container that would have all the options, in my case that was an `ul`. I have no idea where the dropdown is so I can't specify a place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
 <select style="position: absolute;" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;" class="dropdown_list" name="list of majors" id="main_dropdown">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option> <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Thankyou, but I am not sure if it fits in my code as I am not defining option values. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Here is the link to the updated JS fiddle - https://live.datatables.net/xexeraci/1/edit

There is no container that defines the option values. Thanks.

Comment: why not? try this: `var select = $(' <select style="position: absolute;" onmousedown="if(column.data().length>8){this.size=8;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;" class="dropdown_list" name="list"><option value=""></option></select>')`

Comment: I read somewhere that I can define the css in my javascript after loading the values. I am not sure how to do that?

Comment: what is the value of coumn.data() here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the values are automatically populated from columns 0,1, and 2. I am using datatables.